# Set alert rule in azure monitor to trigger alert only the average cpu value for past 30 mins

Tags: azure, triggers, alert, azure-monitor

Im looking for Set alert rule in azure monitor to trigger alert only the average cpu value for past 30 mins is greater than the threshold value.
If creating alert rule using metric condition how to proceed or how to achieve the above scenario?

Looking for the steps to create the cpu/memory alert to avoid multiple alerts in this 30 mins so I need only average value of every 30 mins

I tried query to get the average value but not sure to achieve the process.
So looking for assistance create alert for this to achieve the mentioned scenario

Answer (score 0):

I have created an alert to trigger for every 30 minutes based on Threshold value.
Below are the steps followed.
Select  VM > Left Pane > Select Alerts > New Alerts > In condition or signal select > Percentage CPU

Fill the below details in Percentage CPU alert rule

Threshold : Static
**Aggregation type : Average**
Operator : Greater than
Threshold value : 80
**Check every : 30 minutes**
**Lookback period : 1 hour**
[image]

If you want  to check after 30 minutes change Check every value to 1 hour and Lookback period to 30 minutes.

Comment: Great this really worked and also I enabled automatically resolve alert options in detail tab while creating alert this prevents creating new alert when new one raised and look back previous if that alert is still active it will not trigger new.